# List of champions by fastest move speed

Tags: league-of-legends

I tend to find myself preferring champions with high mobility (Poppy, Evelynn, Singed etc) and I am interested in roaming. No point roaming with a slow champion. (I don't want a list of viable roamers, I roam with Poppy and she isn't recommended)

The move speed has to take into consideration:

- Base move speed
- (Short cooldown) Self move speed buff skills (e.g.Poppy, Zilean's and Nunu's self buffs)
- (Short cooldown) skills that increase mobility (e.g. Rammus' powerball)
- Exclude move speed items, including boots, phantom dancers etc.

Comment: This might be a good place to start http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Movement_Speed

Comment: This too http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Champion_Base_Statistics

Comment: Is there an easy way to format tables without having to use a million & nbsp; ?

Comment: @danixd not really. I used Excel and left a blank row between useful rows so that it pasted with breaks.

Comment: I don't think move speed is the best qualifier for roamers. Having a snare / CC is much more useful than an additional 5 or 10 movespeed.

Comment: I could abbreviate my answer to "just those champions with CC" or another parameter you are looking for in a "roamer".

Comment: @Raven Dreamer I am not looking for a 'roamer' as I stated in the question, I am just after a list of fast moving champs. That is going to influence my playing choice. Having CC is not a necessary, however most champs have CC anyway.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

FORMAT for the information below:

> Champion - Base Move Speed - Ability
>   or Abilities that grant additional
>   Move Speed

> Blitzcrank   -   325 -    Overdrive grants
>   him (16 / 20 / 24 / 28 / 32)%
>   increased movement and (30 / 38 / 46 /
>   54 / 62)% attack speed for 8 seconds.

8 Second duration - 15 Second CD (starts on cast not on end of effect) so there are 7 seconds where you aren't being buffed (1 second if you have 40% cdr)

> Dr. Mundo     -   345 -    Sadism grants him
>   (15 / 25 / 35)% extra movement speed
>   for 12 seconds as well as heals him
>   for 40 / 55 / 70 % of his max health.

12 second duration 75 second cooldown. Sadism may best be used during a fight but using the ability to recover from an engagement while quickly moving to another lane shouldn't be underestimated.

> Evelynn   -   340 -    Dark frenzy grants her A flat (4 / 8 / 12 / 16 / 20) movespeed bonus when she hits an enemy when any ability that stacks 4 times and lasts 3 seconds, and a ( 30 / 40 / 50 / 60 / 70)% movespeed bonus that removes slows and ignores unit collision for 3 seconds when activated 
>   attack speed and (20 / 25 / 30)%
>   movement speed for 10 seconds.

Evelynn is a natural roamer with her invisibility. Also, the cooldown on her Dark Frenzy is reset whenever she gets a kill or assist. Last, the amount of time for her passive to kick in is the same as Boots of Mobility's passive.

> Galio    -   335 -    Righteous Gust creates
>   a directional draft for 5 seconds
>   which increasing the movement speed of
>   allies passing through it by (20 / 25
>   / 30 / 35 / 40)%.

Galio may deserve to be removed from this list as he is not truly a roamer but the ability buffs allies as well as him self and is only not active for 7 seconds at a time (12 second cooldown 5 second duration).

> Gangplank -   345 -    Raise Morale grants
>   him (8 / 10 / 12 / 14 / 16) attack
>   damage and (3 / 4 / 5 / 6 / 7)%
>   movement speed passively. When
>   activated it grants Gangplank (14 /18
>   /22 /26 /30)% movement speed and (20
>   /28 /36 /44 /52) attack damage. Nearby
>   allies receive (7 /9 /11 /13 /15)%
>   movement speed and (10 /14 /18 /22
>   /26) attack damage.

Raise Morale combined with Gangplank's ult can be a very potent combination regardless of allied team composition as it grants all nearby allies the move speed (and a damage) bonus while his ult slows fleeing enemies (or just pounds them if they decide to stay still).

> Garen    -   340 -    Decisive Strike grants
>   him (15 / 20 / 25 / 30 / 35)%
>   increased movement for 3 seconds.

Decisive Strike has an 8 Second cool down with a 3 second duration and Garen's Judgement removes and then reduces slows allowing him to gank more effectively.

> Hecarim - 345 -
>
> Janna    -   335 -    Tailwind increases the
>   movement speed of all allied champions
>   by 3% while she's alive. Zephyr passively increases her movement speed by (8 /
>   10 / 12 / 14 / 16)% and enables her to
>   pass through units.

See Janna's Zephyr ability above. The ability also has an active that slows the target.

> Kayle -   335 -    Divine
>   Blessing increases an allied
>   champion's movement speed by 12% for
>   10 seconds.

Divine blessing has a cooldown of 10 seconds. If you have the mana, you can cast it over and over. Kayle also has an activateable move speed debuff slowing its target by 25% and dealing magic damage.

> Kennen    -   335 -    Lightning Rush grants
>   him a flat bonus to movement equal to
>   his base movement speed (after any
>   other bonuses are calculated) and the
>   ability to move through units for 4
>   seconds.

With a cooldown of 8 seconds and a duration of 4 seconds it would appear that Lightning Rush would significantly increase Kennen's mobility. However, this is only true if he has the opportunity to pass though enemies to recharge his energy as the ability costs 100.

> Malphite -   335 -    Seismic
>   Shard steals (14 / 17 / 20 / 23 / 26)%
>   movement speed from the target for 4
>   seconds.

Seismic Shard requires a target making it limited in its use as a "roaming" skill.

> Master
>   Yi    -   355 -    Highlander increases his
>   movespeed by 40% for 6/9/12 seconds.

Master Yi is an excellent jungler/ganker/roamer with Alpha Strike, Highlander and the highest (tied with Pantheon and Nidalee in cougar form) base move speed (355) allowing him to initiate chase and escape quickly.

> Miss Fortune -   325 -    Strut grants
>   her an additional 25 movement speed
>   after not taking any damage for 7 or
>   more seconds, increasing each second
>   up to 70 maximum bonus speed.

When you are between lanes as you roam you will get progressively faster (to the max of 70).

> Nidalee  -   335 -    Aspect of the
>   Cougar grants her 20 movement speed in
>   cougar form. Prowl grants 15% movement speed when moving through brush and for 2 seconds after she leaves it

In Cougar form Nidalee can also pounce every three seconds at no cost increasing her mobility further.

> Nocturne -   345 -    Duskbringer increases
>   his movespeed by (15 / 20 / 25 / 30 /
>   35)% while in the trail it or the
>   enemy champion leaves.

Nocturne also benefits from a long ranged ult allowing him to gank from quite a distance allowing him to "roam" less but still have a presence.

> Nunu -   315 -    Blood Boil grants an
>   allied unit (25 / 30 / 35 / 40 / 45)%
>   increased attack speed and (8 / 9 / 10 / 11 / 12)% increased movement
>   speed for 15 seconds. If cast on an
>   ally, Nunu also gains the effect of
>   Bloodboil.

Nunu is a good roamer and jungler. His Consume ability allows him to regain some of his lost health between ganks by using it one the monsters found in the jungle (or after a fight on the minions in the lane).

> Poppy -   320 -    Paragon of
>   Demacia grants her (17 / 19 / 21 / 23
>   / 25)% increased movement speed for 5
>   seconds when activated.

Poppy has increased movement speed and excellent tower diving capabilities granted by her ult.

> Rammus   -   310 -    Powerball grants him
>   an increasing bonus to movement speed
>   while active.

Powerball can be activated to increase movement speed between lanes and initiate a fight as it pops up enemies he hits (though this ends the ability).

> Rumble   -   320 -    Scrap Shield grants
>   him (10 / 15 / 20 / 25 / 30)%
>   increased movement speed for 1 second.
>   When in the "Danger Zone" this amount
>   is increased by 30%.

Rumble has a high base move speed and Scrap Shield has a cool down of 6 seconds.

> Singed    -   320 -    Insanity Potion grants him flat (35 / 50 / 65)
>   increased movement speed while active.

Singed naturally benefits from high move speed has a high base move speed and his ult increases it further.

> Teemo    -   305 -    Move Quick increases
>   his movement speed by (10 / 14 / 18 /
>   22 / 26 )%. If Teemo gets hit by a
>   champion or turret while Moving Quick,
>   he gets knocked out of it. He can
>   activate it to gain double the
>   passive, for 3 seconds, which will not
>   be lost even if he is hit.

Teemo can be a good roamer as his increased movement speed allows him to switch lanes or scout the jungle areas quickly. During his excursions he can also drop mushrooms that will grant limited knowledge of where enemy champions are and prevent enemies from ganking/escaping (if they are silly enough to go into the bushes).

> Trundle  -   325 -    Contaminate infects
>   a target location with his curse for 8
>   seconds, granting (20 / 35 / 50 / 65 /
>   80)% attack speed, (20 / 25 / 30 / 35
>   / 40)% movement Speed, and (8 / 11 / 14 / 17 / 20)% healing and regenaration increase while on
>   it.

Trundle grants himself increased move speed and he can use Pillar of Filth slows enemy move speed and block terrain making him an effective roamer.

> Udyr -   320 -    Bear Stance grants him
>   (15 / 18 / 21 / 24 / 27)% increased
>   movement speed for (2 / 2.5 / 3 / 3.5
>   / 4) seconds upon activation.

With a cooldown of 6 seconds there are only 2 seconds (at ability level 5) where Udyr is not increasing his movespeed (if you keep recasting bear stance).

> Vayne -   310 -    Night Hunter gains 40 Movement Speed when
>   moving towards an enemy champion.
>   After activating her ult, Final Hour, the bonus is tripled.

Night Hunter has a range of 2000 allowing you to close on enemy champions from quite a distance fairly quickly. She also has tumble which allows her to chase even more effectively.

> Warwick  -   320 -    Blood Scent senses
>   enemy champions under 50% life within
>   (1500 / 2300 / 3100 / 3900 / 4700)
>   distance of him; while he detects a
>   low-health enemy, he gains (20 / 25 /
>   30 / 35 / 40)% increased movement
>   speed.

Warwick is a natural roamer/ganker with Blood Scent and his ult he can effectively initiate (in small fights) or pick off stragglers.

> Zilean   -   310 -    Time Warp increases
>   an allied champion's movement speed by
>   55% for (2.5 / 3.25 / 4 / 4.75 / 5.5)
>   seconds.

Zilean is best as support but can move quickly between lanes with Time Warp and Rewind. With some cooldown reduction and mana regeneration Zilean can cast Time Warp and Rewind over and over, sustaining the increased move speed.

Other Champions with abilities that grant increased movement without movespeed buffs include  Aatrox, Caitlyn, Corki, Ezreal, Gragas, Graves, Irelia, Jarvan IV, Jax, Kassadin, Katarina, LeBlanc, Lee Sin, Maokai, Renekton, Shaco, Shen, Tristana, Tryndamere, Xin Zhao and Zac. Note these listed immediately prior are abilities that may require targets such as allied or enemy champions to function (examples being Katarina and Jax). Others like Caitlyn I list but her ability really isn't optimally used for movement as much as kiting and escaping.

Big list with lots of potential math to do to get the true fastest but I suspect the goal isn't to just be the fastest. Let me know if I missed something.

Edit: Information contained herein is compiled entirely from the two links provided in my comments to the original question.

Comment: This list has problems, as presented. Most champion move speed abilities are severely limited in duration, cooldown, or useability (for example, Cassieopia's speed increase only happens when she can hit someone with her Q, a situation unlikely to occur when roaming).

Comment: @Raven The question was presented as "I don't want a list of viable roamers." So I simply did the best I could. The original question is very open ended. I also point out that Kassadin and Shaco don't have Move Speed buffs per say but they have abilities that increase their general movement (ie they both have short cooldown blinks).

Comment: I'm not finding fault with your answer; I'm finding fault with the open-endedness of the question. (Though there is something to be said that the question specifies short cooldown abilities)

Comment: I will be updating again to flesh out the abilities of the "other champions" that are listed in paragraph form.

Comment: looks good. Two notes: both Garen and Vayne's Q's don't start their cooldown until the buff times out, making the CD much more when used *just* for travel.

Answer (score 3):

Couple of months ago I made an Excel file crossing data from [League of Legends Wikia](http://www.leagueoflegends.wikia.com) and other sources.

Unfortunately is not updated with latest 2/3 champions added and probably therefore latest 2/3 patches. I will update my answer later, in the meanwhile, but this could be a good start, these are the data I have, ordered by speed.

Now fixed with all champions and last patches:

```
Champion             SPD
Akali                325
Alistar              305
Amumu                310
Anivia               300
Annie                310
Ashe                 300
Blitzcrank           300
Brand                315
Caitlyn              305
Cassiopeia           310
Cho'Gath             315
Corki                300
Dr. Mundo            320
Evelynn              315
Ezreal               305
Fiddlesticks         310
Galio                310
Gangplank            320
Garen                320
Gragas               315
Heimerdinger         300
Irelia               320
Janna                310
Jarvan IV            315
Jax                  325
Karma                310
Karthus              310
Kassadin             315
Katarina             325
Kayle                310
Kennen               310
Kog'Maw              305
LeBlank              310
Lee Sin              325
Lux                  315
Malphite             310
Malzahar             315
Maokai               310
Master Yi            330
Miss Fortune         300
Mordekaiser          315
Morgana              300
Nasus                325
Nidalee              310
Nocturne             320
Nunu                 315
Olaf                 320
Orianna              300
Pantheon             330
Poppy                320
Rammus               310
Renekton             320
Rumble               320
Ryze                 310
Shako                325
Shen                 310
Singed               320
Sion                 315
Sivir                310
Sona                 305
Soraka               310
Swain                310
Taric                315
Teemo                305
Tristana             300
Trundle              325
Tryndamere           320
Twisted Fate         305
Twitch               305
Udyr                 320
Urgot                310
Vayne                305
Veigar               315
Vladimir             310
Warwick              320
Xin Zhao             320
Yorick               315
Zilean               310
```

Comment: It's "Shaco," not Shako.  He will probably cut out your spleen for that.